# How to get the function parameter name generated by kotlin

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I'm writing some like Spring boot. This is an example.
But the file is generate by kotlin.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
class IndexController() {

    @RequestMapping("/index",RequestMethod.GET)
    fun index(@RequestParam version : Int , @RequestParam test:String) : String  = "hello world"

}
```

I want to get the parameters name in that function but i can't get the real name. The name I get was arg0 , arg1.

I use ASM. But still the same.